# How can I wrap each 3 columns with a row using bootstrap/wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, row

I would like to wrap each 3 column with a row using this loop.
I know that I have to use a counter but I don't know where I have to open/close the rows.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="blog" class="sezione">
<section id="content" class="container">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
     if (!is_paged() && $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
            ...
        </div>
    <?php
    } elseif (!is_paged() &&  $wp_query->current_post >= 1 && $wp_query->current_post <= 2 ) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
            ...
        </div>
    <?php 
    } elseif (!is_paged() &&  $wp_query->current_post >= 3 ) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            ...
        </div>
    <?php 
    } elseif ( is_paged() ) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            ...
        </div>
    <?php }
    endwhile;
        // Restore original post data.
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; ?>
    <div>
        <?php posts_nav_link('|', '...'); ?>
    </div>
</section>
</div><!-- /sezione -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//set up counter
$count = 1;
?>

<div id="blog" class="sezione">
<section id="content" class="container">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

// if count is equal to 1 start a row
if ($count === 1){
    echo '<div class="row">';
}

if (!is_paged() && $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
        ...
    </div>
<?php
} elseif (!is_paged() &&  $wp_query->current_post >= 1 && $wp_query->current_post <= 2 ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
<?php 
} elseif (!is_paged() &&  $wp_query->current_post >= 3 ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
<?php 
} elseif ( is_paged() ) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
<?php }

    // if count is equal 3 close row and reset $count
    // or else increment
    if ($count === 3){
        echo '</div>';
        $count = 1;
    }else{
        //increment counter
        $count++;
    }

endwhile;
    // Restore original post data.
    wp_reset_postdata();

endif; ?>
<div>
    <?php posts_nav_link('|', '...'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not correct, because it wraps all the content in a single row.
As I said, I need to wrap every 3 columns inside a row.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the question correctly, I've edited my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I just tried it but it's not correct: it shoots a row that contains first column and a row; in this other row there are the second column and another row...and so on...

Comment: Ok I hadn't tested that code, I just wrote it here from my head. I'll test it on a local install and come back with an edit as I'm sure it's nearly correct.

Comment: I just find the problem, this code:  
// if count is equal 3 close row and reset $count
    // or else increment
    if ($count === 3){
        echo '</div>';
        $count = 1;
    }else{
        //increment counter
        $count++;
    }

have to go before wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: Yes just spotted that myself. You should be all set now.

Comment: I did not realize that it would be totally useless because the desktop layout has 3 columns, but the tablet layout has 2 columns. If I include the 3 columns in a row, than looking at the tablet version it "produce" a 4th blank column.

Comment: Ok I was just answering the original question to try wrap 3 columns in a row in the loop but is there actually a need for the multiple rows is there a reason not to just use columns all in a single row? I'm just trying to get a better idea for what layout you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My attempt was to use flexbox to match the height of the columns, and I had read that I had to apply it to the rows, so first of all I needed rows.

Comment: Maybe you achieve the same using Javascript although if you are changing the number of columns in a row on mobile you probably come across the same problem. Maybe using the bootstrap classes as your js selector and running script on window resize? That's a little bit messy though.